# Get the areas of two shapes I have built in a Arraylist to add together

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on some code that has the user build either a rectangle or triangle by inputting the number of sides of the shape, the numbers associated with those sides (i.e length and width, base and height) and calculate their individual areas and store it in a Arraylist. 
So the problem I am having is that I am stumped on how to get the two areas of the shapes to add together for a TotalArea. The code I am using prints some weird number that is not the the Sum of the two areas. The code is using inheritance and calling from a suberClass and two other SubClasses, so for simplicity reasons I'm an not posting those.
Here is the code in question.

```
//Test Class

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


   public class testPuzzle {

    public static boolean loop = false;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        ArrayList<Polygon> puzzle = new ArrayList<Polygon>();

        int userInput = 0;

        //Main Menu. Use do/while loop
        do {
            System.out.println("\nJigsaw Puzzle \nMenu:");
            System.out.println("1 - Add Polygon");
            System.out.println("2 - Print Polygon List");
            System.out.println("3 - Puzzle Area");
            System.out.println("4 - Exit");

            //Import Scanner
            Scanner keyStroke = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("\nEnter Menu Option: ");
            userInput = keyStroke.nextInt();

            //If statements to build the polygon
            if (userInput == 1){
                System.out.print("Enter Polygon Shape: r for rectangle, t for triangle. ");
                String shape = keyStroke.next();
                if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("r")){
                    System.out.print("Name of Polygon: ");
                    String nameRectangle = keyStroke.next();
                    System.out.print("Number of Sides: ");
                    int numSidesRectangle = keyStroke.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Rectangle Length: ");
                    double lengthRectangle = keyStroke.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("Rectange Width: ");
                    double widthRectangle = keyStroke.nextDouble();
                    Polygon rectangle = new Rectangle(nameRectangle, numSidesRectangle, lengthRectangle, widthRectangle);
                     puzzle.add(rectangle);
                     System.out.println("Polygon added!");
                 }
                 if (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("t")){
                    System.out.print("Name of Polygon: ");
                    String nameTriangle = keyStroke.next();
                    System.out.print("Number of Sides: ");
                    int numSidesTriangle = keyStroke.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Triangle Base: ");
                    double lengthTriangle = keyStroke.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("Triangle Height: ");
                    double widthTriangle = keyStroke.nextDouble();
                    Polygon triangle = new Triangle(nameTriangle, numSidesTriangle, lengthTriangle, widthTriangle);
                    puzzle.add(triangle);
                    System.out.println("Polygon added!");

                } loop =true;
            }

            //calculate polygon areas and print polygon list
            if (userInput == 2){

                System.out.println("Polygon List (Name, Num Sides, Area):");
                for(int index = 0; index<puzzle.size(); index++){
                    Polygon list = puzzle.get(index);
                    System.out.println(list.getName()+", "+ list.getNumSides()+", "+ list.calculateArea());
                }
                loop =true;
            }
            //Print total polygon puzzle area
            if (userInput == 3){
                for(int index = 0; index<puzzle.size(); index++){
                    Polygon list = puzzle.get(index);
                    System.out.println("Total Puzzle Area: "+ list.calculateArea() +     list.calculatArea());

        }
            if  (userInput == 4){
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                System.exit(0);
        }
    }

       while (loop==true);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show us your input and your output?

Comment: It looks like you're adding each area to itself (i.e. doubling it) each time through the loop.  Presumably that's not what you're trying to do.

Comment: One other general comment: use meaningful and accurate variable names.  `list` is a terrible name for the current polygon in the list; `currentPolygon` or `polygon` would be better options.  And classes always start with a capital letter.  ALWAYS.  The compiler will let you start them with a lowercase letter, but that doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're adding each area to itself (i.e. doubling it) each time through the loop. Presumably that's not what you're trying to do, and you should instead be summing up all of the polygons as you go through the list.